# Steepest Descent Sequence

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming, gradient-descent

How can I compute the first three iterates for the steepest descent sequence

$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{(x_1^2+3x_2^2)}{2}$ beginning at $x_0 = (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}})^T$

$\nabla f(x_1,x_2) = \langle 2x_1, 3x_2\rangle$

and $\nabla f(\textbf{x}_0) = \langle .. , ..\rangle$

Assuming my calculations are correct, Where do I proceed from here for the next steps?

How do I draw the trajectory of the iterates towards the minimizer of $f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $\nabla f$ should be $<x_1,3 x_3>$. So the associated matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&3\end{pmatrix}$, and $b=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\end{pmatrix}$

You can then use the formulas

$$r_n=b-Ax_n\\
\alpha_n=\frac{r_n^T r_n}{r_n^T A r^n}\\
x_{n+1}=x_n+\alpha r_n$$

to find the 3 iterations.

Your function is a paraboloid. You can either plot the points on a 3D paraboloid, or plot the points on a contour graph.